# Undefined _path error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd seen many similar questions but I still can't resolve this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `import_home_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fdcf7810ca0>:0x007fdcf7813108>
```

Heres the route file:

```
resources :home do
    collection { post :import}
end
```

Heres the rake routes:

```
           Prefix Verb   URI Pattern              Controller#Action
import_home_index POST   /home/import(.:format)   home#import
       home_index GET    /home(.:format)          home#index
                  POST   /home(.:format)          home#create
         new_home GET    /home/new(.:format)      home#new
        edit_home GET    /home/:id/edit(.:format) home#edit
             home GET    /home/:id(.:format)      home#show
                  PATCH  /home/:id(.:format)      home#update
                  PUT    /home/:id(.:format)      home#update
                  DELETE /home/:id(.:format)      home#destroy
        home_test GET    /home/test(.:format)     home#test
```

Heres the show.html.erb that calls `import_home_path`

```
<%= form_tag import_home_path, multipart: true do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag "Import CSV" %>
<% end %>
```

I'm just trying to do a simple test with the [tutorial here](http://richonrails.com/articles/importing-csv-files). But stumbled in named helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to routes your path would be `import_home_index_path`, not `import_home_path`.

Comment: So named helpers will be Prefix`_path` yeah?